# Row Grouping in Angular Datatable v0.4.0

Tags: angularjs, datatable

I am trying to use row grouping in current version of angular datable (http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/) but not getting any clue how to implement it. I have a json data that has a format:

```
vm.data=[
   {
     'groupName': 'Match 1',
     'content':[{'id': 1, 'name': abc'}]
   }
]
```

This is what the html look like:

I am not sure how this will go from there. I found out in other issues, there is a suggestion to use event:dataTableLoaded on $scope but it seems like the eventit is not available in the current version. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used that version of datatables but this work for me in

```
   $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder
   .fromFnPromise(reportService.getReportData($scope.reportInfo,
   $scope.model))
       .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
       .withOption('fnDrawCallback',
           function(oSettings) {
              var api = this.api();
              var rows = api.rows({ page: 'current' }).nodes();
              var last = null;
              api.column(0, { page: 'current' })
              .data()
              .each(function(group, i) {
              if (last !== group) {
                 $(rows)
                 .eq(i)
                 .before(
                 '<tr class="group"><td colspan="5">' + group + '</td></tr>');
                                    last = group;
                                }
                            });
                    })
```

Answer (score 0):

just add one more withOption to your datatable.**columIndex** have the index of your column where you want to do group.this is work for me in **angular-datatables v0.6.x**

```
.withOption('fnDrawCallback', function (oSettings) {
    var api = this.api();
    var rows = api.rows( {page:'current'} ).nodes();
    var last=null;
    columIndex = 1
    api.column(columIndex, {page:'current'} ).data().each( function ( group, i ) {
        if ( last !== group ) { 
            colspan = Object.keys($scope.dtColumnPermission).length ; 
            $(rows).eq( i ).before(
                '<tr class="groupColumns"><td colspan="'+colspan+'">'+group+'</td></tr>'
            ); 
            last = group;
        }
    } );
})
```

Answer (score 0):

this is working for me using **angular-datatables": "^8.0.0"**

> drawCallback

```
this.dtOptions = {
  lengthMenu: [5, 10, 15, 25],
  pageLength: 5,
  ordering: false,
  processing: true,
  searching: false,
  drawCallback(setting) {
    console.log("setting is  ", setting)
    var api = this.api();
    var rows = api.rows({ page: 'current' }).nodes();
    console.log("rows is ", rows);
    var last = null;
    const columIndex = 0;
    api.column(columIndex, { page: 'current' }).data().each(function (group, i) {
      if (last !== group) {

        $(rows).eq(i).before(
          '<tr style="color: crimson !important;background-color: blanchedalmond;" class="groupColumns"><td style="display: none;"></td><td>' + "        " + group + '</td><td></td></tr>'
        );
        last = group;
      }
    });

  }




};
```